# Environment Variable " " not defined

Tags: batch-file

```
: arena1.2
cls
set /a EnemyName= (%random% %% 20)+1
if %EnemyName% equ 1 set %EnemyName1% Racket
if %EnemyName% equ 2 set %EnemyName1% Amok
if %EnemyName% equ 3 set %EnemyName1% Banter
if %EnemyName% equ 4 set %EnemyName1% Drollery
if %EnemyName% equ 5 set %EnemyName1% Keumray
if %EnemyName% equ 6 set %EnemyName1% Quaemi
if %EnemyName% equ 7 set %EnemyName1% Raksul
if %EnemyName% equ 8 set %EnemyName1% Nafl
if %EnemyName% equ 9 set %EnemyName1% Zoda
if %EnemyName% equ 10 set %EnemyName1% Finje
if %EnemyName% equ 11 set %EnemyName1% Liffin
if %EnemyName% equ 12 set %EnemyName1% Reafdaw
if %EnemyName% equ 13 set %EnemyName1% Gleadey
if %EnemyName% equ 14 set %EnemyName1% Gant
if %EnemyName% equ 15 set %EnemyName1% Prooq
if %EnemyName% equ 16 set %EnemyName1% Nazu
if %EnemyName% equ 17 set %EnemyName1% Jape
if %EnemyName% equ 18 set %EnemyName1% Ridiculous
if %EnemyName% equ 19 set %EnemyName1% Vicious
if %EnemyName% equ 20 set %EnemyName1% Ludicrous
if %EnemyName% equ 21 set %EnemyName1% Bedlam
set /a EnemyTitle= (%random% %% 20)+1
if %EnemyTitle% equ 1 set %enemyt% The Hammer
if %EnemyTitle% equ 2 set %enemyt% The Destroyer
if %EnemyTitle% equ 3 set %enemyt% The Mountain
if %EnemyTitle% equ 4 set %enemyt% The Filthy
if %EnemyTitle% equ 5 set %enemyt% The Ugly
if %EnemyTitle% equ 6 set %enemyt% The Handsome
if %EnemyTitle% equ 7 set %enemyt% The Inconsiderate
if %EnemyTitle% equ 8 set %enemyt% The Friendly
if %EnemyTitle% equ 9 set %enemyt% The Biter
if %EnemyTitle% equ 10 set %enemyt% The Muzzled
if %EnemyTitle% equ 11 set %enemyt% The Claw
if %EnemyTitle% equ 12 set %enemyt% The Scarred
if %EnemyTitle% equ 13 set %enemyt% The Burned
if %EnemyTitle% equ 14 set %enemyt% The Flammable
if %EnemyTitle% equ 15 set %enemyt% The Extinguisher of Life
if %EnemyTitle% equ 16 set %enemyt% The Dumb
if %EnemyTitle% equ 17 set %enemyt% The Smart
if %EnemyTitle% equ 18 set %enemyt% The Wise
if %EnemyTitle% equ 19 set %enemyt% The Old
if %EnemyTitle% equ 20 set %enemyt% The Necromancer
if %EnemyTitle% equ 21 set %enemyt% The Revived
echo.
echo And in this corner, %EnemyName1% %enemyt%!
echo.
pause
```

Comment: Which line are you getting this error on? What debugging have you done?

Comment: it is a random name gen so the if commands are where i am getting the error on. I have tried some debugging but I cant figure out the problem with the program atm. It is specifically popping up Enviroment variable Vicious not defined.

Comment: your `if` is ok. It's your `set` that is wrong. It should read `set EnemyName1=Racket`

Comment: thanks. it is working now! been trying to fix this one problem for a while now.

Comment: A side-note: `set /a (%random% %% 20)+1` returns numbers from `1` to `20` but never `21`!

Answer (score 0):

1
your if is ok. It's your set that is wrong. It should read set EnemyName1=Racket – Stephan 10 mins ago

thanks this works.

Comment: also try `for /f "tokens=%EnemyName%" %%a in ("Racket Amok Banter Drollery Keumray Quaemi Raksul Nafl Zoda Finje Liffin Reafdaw Gleadey Gant Prooq Nazu Jape Ridiculous Vicious Ludicrous Bedlam")  do set EnemyName1=%%a`

Comment: and `for /f "tokens=%EnemyTitle% delims=," %%a in ("The Hammer,The Destroyer, ... ") do set enemyt=%%a`